# How can I install a newer python on Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7

I'd like to install a newer python 2.7 on trusty.

Installing "python" installs python 2.7. The newest version available on trusty is 2.7.6. I'd like to install the most updated version of 2.7. I am not interested in python 3.

To do this I would have to add a new source to apt. Which is a good source to use?

Comment: It comes with python 3 by default

Comment: Which is your current `Python` version? Could you add the output of this command to question: `python --version`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've now added more detail to my question.

Comment: Note you can *break* your system doing this - **caveat emptor** applies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This PPA should have the latest version of Python 2.7:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
```

Add it by running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and it should upgrade Python.

Comment: It is a good idea to add the related public key to the keyring via `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 5BB92C09DB82666C`, to avoid the "The following signatures couldn't be verified..." message during `apt-get update`.